# Proving a given set of vectors on one side of a hyperplane is a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ be $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Assume that there exists a hyperplane $H$ through the origin such that $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ are strictly on one side of $H$.  Also assume that the angle between any two vectors $v_i$ and $v_j$ is obtuse.  Then show that $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I'm at a loss for how to proceed.  Since they explicitly mention angle I'm assuming I might need to use the dot product or something, but that's about as far as I got.

Comment: Take a look ar R3 and imagine 3 vectors that all have obtuse angles with one another. Then why can't you have them on one side of a given plane? Establish a proof by contradiction in the R3 case. With that information try to extend it into Rn

Comment: @imranfat I'm not sure I understand your comment.  By supposition, they are all on one side of the hyperplane.  Are you saying that can't happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the vectors are all in the half-space $ax > 0$, and that some linear combination of them is zero, $c_1 v_1 + \dots + c_n v_n = 0$.

Then, $a(c_1v_1 + \dots + c_nv_n) = c_1(av_1) + c_2(av_2) + \dots + c_n(av_n) = 0$, so if any $c_i$ is non-zero, there must be coefficients of both positive and negative signs. Now we can relabel so that $c_1, c_2, \dots, c_j$ are the positive coefficients and $c_{k}, c_{k+1},\dots,c_n$ are the negative coefficients.

Now, both of the vectors $v = c_1v_1 + c_2v_2 + \dots + c_jv_j$ and $w = (-c_{k})v_{k} + (-c_{k+1})v_{k+1} + \dots + (-c_n)v_n$ have positive coefficients, and $v = w$, so what happens if we try to compute $\|v\|^2 = v \cdot w$?